# How can I use query in router.php of codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a list of router such as:

```
$route['mobile'] = 'parrent_list';
$route['tables'] = 'parrent_list';
$route['laptop'] = 'parrent_list';
$route['gamer'] = 'parrent_list';
```

My router.php have about 100 row. I dont't want set it manual. So i want know how can I use query in router to get my categories in database.
Example:

```
require_once( BASEPATH .'database/DB'. EXT );
$db =& DB();
$query = $db->get( 'categories' )->where( 'parrent_id', 0 );
$result = $query->result();
foreach( $result as $row )
{
    $route[ $row->slug ]                 = 'parrent_list;
    $route[ $row->slug.'/:any' ]         = 'parrent_list;

}
```

I try but it don't work.
Thanks all.

Comment: perhaps fixing the syntax errors would help

Comment: I get error
Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_result::where() in D:\Web\Host\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\application\config\routes.php on line 44
but when I write $query = $db->get( 'categories' ); . It's work!!! However, this result is not what I want.